# How to find absolute minimum with NMinimize

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, functions, graphics3d, parametric-functions

So I have a trefoil and twisted cubic that are very close to intersecting but do not. I know `NMinimize` can be used to best approximate the minimum, but it supposedly isn't perfect.

How can I precisely find where the absolute minimum occurs how close these two are to intersecting. What else would I want to use in addition to `NMinimize`?

Function:
$$
f(a,b)=b^6 \sin ^2\left(\frac{3 a}{2}\right)+\left(\sin
   (a) \left(\cos \left(\frac{3
   a}{2}\right)+2\right)-b^2\right)^2+\cos (a)
   \cos \left(\frac{3 a}{2}\right)-b^2+2
$$

`NMinimize` output: `{1.53724, {a -> 1.69939, b -> 1.04861}}` (how do I interpret this???)

Complete Code:

```
F[a_, b_] := ((2 + Cos[3 a/2] Cos[a]) - (b)^2 
           + (((2 + Cos[3 a/2]) Sin[a]) - (b^2))^2) 
           + (Sin[3 a/2] (b^3))^2 ;

ContourPlot[
 F[a, b], {a, -1, 1}, {b, 0, 4Pi}, 
 Contours -> 20]

NMinimize[(((2 + 
         Cos[3 a/2] Cos[a]) - (b))^2 + (((2 + Cos[3 a/2]) Sin[
          a]) - (b^2))^2) + (Sin[3 a/2] (b^3))^2, {a, b}]
```

Comment: Do you have any sort of initial code or minimum working example written in Wolfram Language for Mathematica?

Comment: f[a_,b_] (2 - b + Cos[a] Cos[(3a)/2])^2 + (-b^2 + (2 + Cos[(3a)/2]) Sin[a])^2 + b^6 Sin[(3a)/2]^2

Comment: I now edited it

Comment: What is your complete code?

Comment: I just added it in

Comment: If you are asking how to interpret `{1.53724, {a -> 1.69939, b -> 1.04861}}`, it means that the minimum value of your function is  1.53724 and occurs when  {a = 1.69939, b = 1.04861}`.

Comment: @user80088 In my answers I find negative optimal values, therefore not compatible with a minimal euclidian distance. Are you sure about your objective function $F$?

Answer (score 7):

Do you want to consider the distance of two parametric curves `u[a]` and `v[b]` as below?

```
u[a_] := {2 + Cos[3 a/2] Cos[a], (2 + Cos[3 a/2]) Sin[a], Sin[3 a/2]};
v[b_] := {b, b^2, b^3};
sol = NMinimize[{EuclideanDistance[u[a], v[b]], 
    0 <= a <= 4 π, -2 <= b <= 2}, {a, b}];
dist = Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.02], Point[u[a]], Point[v[b]], 
     PointSize[.02], Thickness[.01], Blue, Line[{u[a], v[b]}]} /. sol[[2]]];

Show[{ ParametricPlot3D[u[a], {a, 0, 4 π}, PlotStyle -> Yellow],
       ParametricPlot3D[v[b], {b, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Green], dist}, 
       PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, except with the constraints of the trefoil being -1 to 1 and not -2 to 2. How do I find that blue line value?

Comment: @user80088  sol[[1]] is the distance  what you want.

Comment: Yes, I want the distance

Answer (score 3):

Each such situation has its particulars; when the function is non-convex you have to do some prior investigation. Here you can start with

```
F[a_, b_] := ((2 + Cos[3 a/2] Cos[a]) - (b)^2 + (((2 + Cos[3 a/2]) Sin[a])
            -(b^2))^2) + (Sin[3 a/2] (b^3))^2;
{FunctionPeriod[F[a, b], a], FunctionPeriod[F[a, b], b]}
Limit[F[a, b], b -> Infinity]

(*
{4 \[Pi], 0}
\[Infinity] Sin[(3 a)/2]^2
*)
```

which is a starting point for a first plot:

```
Plot3D[F[a, b], {a, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {b, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b"}]
```

[image]

That tells you the minimum is likely close to 0. Now you change the `PlotRange` to have a better idea.

```
Plot3D[F[a, b], {a, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {b, -2, 2}, 
       PlotRange -> {-2, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b"}]
```

[image]

That shows you that your function is rather "un-convex" in that it has a number of local minimae. You can then move this graphic around to get a feel for where the absolute minimum is located and use that as a starting point of a local search. The point $(-4.5,\,1.8)$ seems about right. Then perform the local search using `FindMinimum` (a better choice because you can set a starting point, as opposed to `NMinimize` that has no such option):

```
sol = FindMinimum[F[a, b], {{a, -4.5}, {b, 1.8}}]
{a, b, F[a, b]} /. Last@sol
p = Point[{a, b, F[a, b]} /. Last@sol]
Show[g, Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.03], p}]]
*(
{-1.3495, {a -> -4.19328, b -> -1.76185}}
*)
```

(this is the value of $F$ and the optimal point). Then move the graphic around to make sure the local minimum is a global one (here you can trust the graphic because the function is regular enough):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Approach based on `NMinimize`**

To add to my other answer, an option is to go with `NMinimize` using a method that performs well with rather *non-convex* functions such as `RandomSearch`.

```
F[a_, b_] := ((2 + Cos[3 a/2] Cos[a]) - (b)^2 + (((2 + Cos[3 a/2]) Sin[a])
            -(b^2))^2) + (Sin[3 a/2] (b^3))^2;
NMinimize[F[a, b], {a, b}, Method -> "RandomSearch"]
(* {-1.3495, {a -> 20.9395, b -> 1.76185}} *)
```

**Comment**. As you can see this method yields the same optimal minimal value (-1.3495). The $(a,b)$ solution is different in $a$ but this is due to the fact that $F$ is $a$-periodic. However a search method with random starting point is only *probably*-effective, so there is no garantee that the solution is a global minimum. For that you need to examine the 3d-plot (see my other answer).

Comment: `NMinimize[F[a, b], {a, b}, 
 Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 3}]` performs `{-1.3495,{a->3552.09,b->-1.76185}}`.